# Vega add static field to data

Tags: aggregate, vega-lite, vega

I'm aiming to create a data table with specific color for each line in vega.

Actually i manage to do it like [that](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRtZRWwY44s3UkXbYNzNrgAPJAhwAbOJWkgA7jSy9GgAzAAMYTLwNGRYaAIRMjhIsrI04mTxMrJImCioANqg4m5waCB5TF6+xEgeDApoRSAAAmoICnnuaACMMhBwiqSK5QDKg8PaPSAAvlKgbTQdEF04aABM-RODY9u267Pzre2dbmuoIVtDO+jj17YhhwsnK2doACxXw7v32u9PxyWp26qAEXxuIDukwEAMWy1WaAAbOCRrc9tpEbCXgjUAB2FE-Sa4rFA14ggAcBLRv3JJPhb1QAE4qZD0Yy6cDzpEQAN7oTBtowrMALozYX9GIlDwQJrFUrlUx+AD6UDYHjYIxktXqZXQiksvgkspAcFI4kwMr1cCgmFQUA8hgA1r5zDlMLqQIqVWqNdoALwB7QAcn1siD2gA-MG-DA6HBw6hg6GgyKxf0oHVGoU5R1ygBPaCZ3yYPMWcoO8RwGy+WRsZDpNCgN35CpIKplGQAMxocA8snKcM5h09SAyHuisUwAJKufQqvVmoqpY9GrSUprdaQDdQTdyLcq1S7Pb7A+xbzmI7HjZ5sEQHoz7rIGrz6yFMzTIGQikdluaM49iq+J2pgINezblAeZQXiWZZWjavhwOIqryNeiHuqioB5tehbVOgBYZoeIDdr2-boIOZJrP0GpTug8jQIha6ZBeE5xDuIDag08RhBezjXhxurhNxMjOAcbH8WgQlETQHgeHxdScVa-bvjIrq5LqoDdjJ2GSnUCpsMq84arM75zKAMEeu6zhTl2IFgXuel+MOiHIepJrmjcoC8WxxEnugvEyGwnadgMNHrAIF5Yd5x6kSAWEBUFIXXj5MUsdZn4MB4NFhJQ4UXppsnZhUnTlKq5qKPomAABRBjGcZBlI2hugwCCUPlACU2gAHx2BImDlSs1VVEgUCOvVjW5M1rXSR4bU1PJHq1e6ALiegQ0jSKMh1JKck6uWcCdlOF56AMFauStn6BLI1TQS4NEadF5RNS15EIiZplLrBRVWUBtlseBer6U5SFsChbFoR5IBefdJHlP5ICBcFcA0T0EQRUlD14YaCVI+jMPoKlvgIBlWU5cpUlaYV7orCVvX9VVNWxu6Y1PVNMkdd1pV9RVg0eMNo0NSz7Vzbt6CLVBRznWtzofltZAaKA51eAdw7Hb26RnfN5QIJd10yJZd1SXjcgTS1vLfG9opAA)

My problem is : when I click on a rectangle, it change the color of all the rectangle not only the one I clicked on.

I did not found a way to make my signals values dependent on each of my row so i decided to add a data to each row. At first i tried to use an `aggregation` but none of the `aggregation` i found allow me to set a static value in a field.
Then i thought a `calculate` could do it but it results in a `Property calculate is not allowed`
Right now I'm stuck and I don't know at all how i could do so.

If anyone has an idea on how I could do it, I would really appreciate. Thanks by advance